# Update color cell on Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, colors, bootstrap-table

I'm using this Bootstrap-table plugin: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

The table is working well. I'm using ajax to push a json array. After the table is finished, I have a Button. When This button Is clicked It will call some functions, and need to update some cell colors. I've a code example below:

```
if (condition is tru){

    $table.bootstrapTable('updateCell', {
        index: 0,
        field: 'SrcPath',
        value: 'new value'
    });
}
```

With `updateCell` I can change the current value... Is there any way to change the background color instead of value?

Comment: please provide workable example!

Answer (score 0):

You can add contextual colors to `<td>` and`<td>` tag. Also you can inline style each elements by using style="....".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="info">John</td>
        <td class="danger">Doe</td>
        <td style="background-color:grey">john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> To modify the table you have to listen on events of table in this case
> you can use the `postBody` event. The table will be rerendered after
> some actions, so the styling must be applied again.
>
> Example: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/UtechtDustin/13775

Source: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/6527

Example code duplicate:

```html
<div id="toolbar">
  <button id="button" class="btn btn-secondary">append</button>
</div>
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-toolbar="#toolbar"
  data-height="460"
  data-url="json/data1.json">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script>
  var $table = $('#table')
  var $button = $('#button')

  function randomData() {
    var startId = ~~(Math.random() * 100)
    return {
        'id': startId,
        'name': 'test' + (startId),
        'price': '$' + (startId)
      }
  }

  $(function() {
    $table.on('post-body.bs.table', () => {
      document.querySelector('tr[data-index="1"]').
        children[0].
        classList.add('table-danger');
    })

    $button.click(function () {
      $table.bootstrapTable('insertRow', {
            index: "3",
            row: randomData(),
          })
    })
  })
</script>
```